# Not able to add Items to Database

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

// This is a continuation of the questions I have asked from a tutorial by Paul Hudson on youtube -

I have tried to add items to a database (see image below) -

[image]

When I should click on the "Add" button on the image above, the boxes should become EMPTY (See image below). Though .Quantum Pizza will not be added to the list of .Statin Island Pizza and .Country pizza, because I have not done further coding), but it should be as the image below -

[image]

but, the result is as follows -

[image]

Now, I am posting the codes -----

configure.swift -

```swift
import  Fluent
import FluentSQLite
import Vapor
import Leaf // added

public func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws {
    // Register routes to the router
    let router = EngineRouter.default()
    try routes(router)
    services.register(router, as: Router.self)

    let leafProvider = LeafProvider()    // added
    try services.register(leafProvider)  // added
    config.prefer(LeafRenderer.self, for: ViewRenderer.self)// added

    let directoryConfig = DirectoryConfig.detect()
    services.register(directoryConfig)
    try services.register(FluentSQLiteProvider())
    var databaseConfig = DatabasesConfig()
    let db = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .file(path:"\(directoryConfig.workDir)pizza.db"))

    databaseConfig.add(database: db, as: .sqlite)
    services.register(databaseConfig)

    var migrationConfig = MigrationConfig()
    migrationConfig.add(model: Pizza.self, database: .sqlite)
    services.register(migrationConfig)
    let serverConfigure = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "0.0.0.0", port: 9090)
    services.register(serverConfigure)
}
```

routes.swift -

```swift
import Routing
import Vapor
import FluentSQLite

public func routes(_ router: Router) throws {
    router.get { req -> Future <View> in
        let Newyorker = Pizza(id: 5, name: "Statin Island Pizza", description: "Impractical Jokers Funny Pizza", price: 55)
        let Traditional = Pizza(id: 5, name: "Country Pizza ", description: "Johny Cash Special", price: 55)

        return try req.view().render("welcome",["pizza":[Newyorker,Traditional]])
    }

    router.post(Pizza.self, at: "add") { req, pizza -> Future<Response> in
        return pizza.save(on:req).map(to:Response.self) { Pizza in
            return req.redirect(to: "/")
        }
    }
}
```

pizza.swift -

```swift
import Foundation
import Vapor
import FluentSQLite

struct Pizza: Encodable, Content, Decodable, SQLiteModel, Migration {
    var id:  Int?
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var price: Int
}
```

leaf screenshot (I tried to paste code, but couldn't, in the correct format. So  adding screeshot) -

[image]

Edit 1: screenshot after I click on the Add button -

[image]

Ill be happy to provide you any further information if you need. 
Also, I would like to know if the title of my question should be modfied or anyhing should be added to it. Thank you.

Comment: is it this line? `router.post(Pizza.self, at: "add")` the `/add` in your `routes.swift`  instead of `add`?

Comment: I'm afraid its not.  you mean the leaf file I  guess. Anyways, I tried all the combinations of "/add" and "add" in the leaf file as well as routes.swift, didn't work out. What am I missing out on ?

Comment: Now, its showing one more error, of which I  am pasting screenshot above(Edit 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forms action should be `action="add"` (you're missing the closing quotation to close the action)

Comment: I  can show you the screenshot of the tutorial. It is the way I have written it. The link to the tutorial is - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSgWwyj1gX4  . see 43rd minute.

Comment: The screenshot you've provided of your Leaf file is missing the `"` - is that screenshot wrong?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it should be -   <form method=“post” action=“/add">  , but with that as well its not working.

Comment: What url does it direct to with that change?

Comment: when I  click on the add button, it shows in the address bar - "http://localhost:9090/%E2%80%9C/add%22?%E2%80%9Cname%E2%80%9D=Quantum+Pizza&%E2%80%9Cdescription=Another+Dimension+Pizza&%E2%80%9Cprice%E2%80%9D=55" . I copied and pasted from the address bar, but its not the same thing I copied. It is somehow  changed, so pasting screenshot after I click on the Add button. See Edit 1 in my main question.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: That's a different error - like it says, you can't call `wait()`

Comment: what do you mean by  generated HTML?

Answer (score 0):

based on OxTim's answer - 
 It was. a simple leaf-formatting/inverted-comma issue.

correct leaf formatted -

```
 <! DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
 <h1> Pizza </h1>
 <p> Welcome to best pizza in the Andromeda Galaxy.
  <ul>
  #for(pizza in pizza) {
  <li> #(pizza.name) </li>
}
 </ul>

 <form method="post" action="/add">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p
<p>Description: <input type="text" name="description" /></p>
 <p>Price: <input type="number" name="price" /></p>
 <button type="submit">Add</button>
 </form>
```