# How to link vapor to ViewController / how to copy vapor models to IOS / how to import vapor package to IOS project (Xcode 10)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model, vapor

I have an Xcode project Pizaco which gives error -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var pizzas = pizza() // Error - Use of unresolved identifier 'Pizza'
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

The "Pizza" in the aforementioned error is from the vapor project (which works fine), would you care to see - [Not able to add Items to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545558/not-able-to-add-items-to-database/59552214#59552214)

when I try to create a package file( because I want to create models), which gives the following error -

```
   // swift-tools-version:4.2
  // The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

     import PackageDescription // error -  No such module 'PackageDescription'
     import UIKit
     import vapor

    let package = Package(
    name: "Pizaco",
     products: [
    .library(name: "Pizaco", targets: ["App"]),
     ],
     dependencies: [
    //  A server-side Swift web framework.
    .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "3.0.0"),

    //  Swift ORM (queries, models, relations, etc) built on SQLite      3.
    .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite.git", from: "3.0.0"),
    .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/leaf.git", from: "3.0.0"),

    ],
   targets: [
    .target(name: "App", dependencies: ["Leaf","FluentSQLite", "Vapor"]),
    .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
    .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: ["App"])
  ]
  )
```

I know the above (No such module 'PackageDescription') error is not there in Xcode 11 (but I have Xcode 10 and I do not want to upgrade to 11 due to some reasons)
So, someone in the discordapp.com (vapor chat) forum told me to copy models directly from the vapor app to iOS app. So, one of my main questions is how to copy models to current project from vapor app?

Is there any other simple way to link IOS and vapor projects?

Comment: *"copy models to current project from vapor app?"* - File copy.  You could consider using a shared library which used by both the vapor and iOS App, but I couldn't tell you exactly how that should work as I don't use vapor

Comment: Nodes wrote an article about sharing code between Vapor and iOS: https://engineering.nodesagency.com/categories/vapor/ios/2019/08/22/Sharing-code-between-iOS-and-Vapor Does that help you?